# Blazor Table Component with fixed header and columns

Tags: html-table, components, blazor

I'm wondering if there's a Blazor component framework  just like the Ant design's table component,which has fixed header and columns both sides.
[image]

Or can you tell me if there's any method to fix my columns?
My table consists several different self-defined components.These components make up the whole table.Part of the code is as follows.(I use two tables to complete the fixed header function.)

```
<div id="KeyData" class="text-left table-container">
        <div class="head-container text-left">
            <table class="head-table" style="border:2px solid black;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="@(1000+200*VarientCount)">
                <tr class="text-center" style="background-color: #99CCFF;">
                    <th width="600" colspan="3" rowspan="2">描述 <br> Description </th>
                    <th width="200" style="background-color: #FFFF99" colspan="@VarientCount">
                        变量 / Variant
                        <MatButton  OnClick="AddVariant">Add</MatButton>
                    </th>

                    <th width="200" rowspan="2">单位  <br> Unit</th>

                    <th width="200" rowspan="2">备注  <br> Comments</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center" style="background-color: #FFFF99">

                    @for (int i = 0; i < VarientCount; i++)
                    {
                        var iCopy = i;
                        <th width="200">
                            @(i + 1)
                            <MatIconButton Icon="clear" OnClick="@(()=>RemoveVariant(iCopy))" Class="after"></MatIconButton>
                        </th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="content-container text-left">
            <table class="content-table" style="border:2px solid black;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="@(1000+200*VarientCount)">
                <KeyDataSupplierInfo KeyData="@l_VKDTI_TSI" />
                <KeyDataVehicleInfo KeyData="@l_VKDTI_VI" />
                <KeyDataDimension KeyData="@l_VKDTI_DIMENSIONS" />
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

KeyDataSupplierInfo Component as follows(Part code)

```
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="200" class="text-center" rowspan="8">
        Third-party Supplier Info<br>
        第三方供应商信息*
    </td>

    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="400" class="text-center" colspan="2">
        EMS <br>
    </td>

    @for (int i = 0; i < KeyData.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        <td width="200" class="text-center bgcolor "  >
            <MatTextField @bind-Value=@KeyData[index].EMS />
        </td>

    }
   
    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="200" class="text-center">
        -
    </td>

    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="200" class="text-center" rowspan="8">
        备注：品牌厂商、软件版本号
    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="400" class="text-center" colspan="2">
        TCU <br>
    </td>

    @for (int i = 0; i < KeyData.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        <td width="200" class="text-center"  >
            <MatTextField @bind-Value=@KeyData[index].TCU />
        </td>
    }

    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="200" class="text-center">
        -
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="400" class="text-center" colspan="2">
        HCU <br>
    </td>
    @for (int i = 0; i < KeyData.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        <td width="200" class="text-center"  >
            <MatTextField @bind-Value=@KeyData[index].HCU  />
        </td>
    }
    <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="200" class="text-center">
        -
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a Blazor component library for Ant Design: [Ant Design Blazor](https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/)

It includes the exact table component you are referring to [here](https://antblazor.com/en-US/components/table)

Example code with a fixed column and header is as follows:

```cs
@using System.ComponentModel
<Table DataSource="data" PageSize="50" ScrollX="1300" ScrollY="240px">
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Name" Width="100" Fixed="left" />
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Age" Width="100" Fixed="left" />
    <Column Title="Column 1" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <Column Title="Column 2" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <Column Title="Column 3" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <Column Title="Column 4" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <Column Title="Column 5" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <Column Title="Column 6" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <Column Title="Column 7" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <Column Title="Column 8" @bind-Field="@context.Address" />
    <ActionColumn Title="Action" Width="100" Fixed="right">
        <a>action</a>
    </ActionColumn>
</Table>

@code {
    class Column
    {
        [DisplayName("Full Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    Column[] data = new Column[] {
        new()
        {
            Name = "John Brown",
            Age = 32,
            Address = "New York Park"
        },
        new()
        {
            Name = "Jim Green",
            Age = 40,
            Address = "London Park"
        },
    };

}
```